# Difference between XmlDocumentFragment and XmlNode in .Net

Tags: c#, xml

I don't understand the difference between `XmlDocumentFragment` and `XmlNode`.

I understand that the first one is a derived type of the second one.

Why is it better to use `XmlDocumentFragment` to create or edit the nodes of an `XmlDocument` in the code ?

Comment: As an aside, you'll have a much nicer experience using `XDocument` rather than `XmlDocument` if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocumentFragment@cs/1/XmlDocumentFragment@cs):

> DocumentFragment is a "lightweight" or "minimal"  Document object. It
>   is very common to want to be able to extract a portion of a document's
>   tree or to create a new fragment of a  document. Imagine implementing
>   a user command like cut or rearranging a document by moving fragments
>   around. It is desirable to have an object which can hold such
>   fragments and it is quite natural to use a Node for this purpose.
>   While it is true that a Document object could  fulfil this role,  a
>   Document object can potentially be a heavyweight  object, depending on
>   the underlying implementation. What is  really needed for this is a
>   very lightweight object.  DocumentFragment is such an object.
>   Furthermore, various operations -- such as inserting nodes as children
>   of another Node -- may take DocumentFragment objects as arguments; 
>   this results in all the child nodes of the DocumentFragment  being
>   moved to the child list of this node. The children of a
>   DocumentFragment node are zero or more  nodes representing the tops of
>   any sub-trees defining the structure of the document. DocumentFragment
>   nodes do not need to be  well-formed XML documents (although they do
>   need to follow the rules  imposed upon well-formed XML parsed
>   entities, which can have multiple top nodes).  For example, a
>   DocumentFragment might have only one  child and that child node could
>   be a Text node. Such a structure model  represents neither an HTML
>   document nor a well-formed XML document. When a DocumentFragment is
>   inserted into a  Document (or indeed any other Node that may take
>   children) the children of the DocumentFragment and not the 
>   DocumentFragment  itself are inserted into the  Node. This makes the
>   DocumentFragment very useful when the user wishes to create nodes that
>   are siblings; the  DocumentFragment acts as the parent of these nodes
>   so that the user can use the standard methods from the Node 
>   interface, such as insertBefore() and  appendChild().

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. The text you quote argues that an `XmlDocumentFragment` is better to use that an `XmlDocument` for a "big" xml manipulation. But I still don't get why it is better compared to an `XmlNode`. Maybe there is something very simple that I couldn't understand...

Comment: @SylvainB. `XmlDocument` is a subtype of `XmlNode` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx So, they are very common and `XmlDocumentFragment` better than `XmlDocument` and `XmlNode` in some cases

Comment: ok. I was asking the question because with the property `XmlNode.InnerXml` you can build a whole complex node and insert it in an `XmlDocument`. I guess the answer to my question is at the end of your answer : with `XmlDocumentFragment` you can handle nodes that are siblings.